# Lloyd's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, k-means

Is it possible to run Lloyd's algorithm to find the k-means in one-dimension in  polynomial-time?

I know that that the k-means problem is NP-hard for anything more than one-dimensions. 
Any if you have a fixed dimension, Lloyd's algorithm will run in polynomial time, right?

Comment: Clearly homework question or what? I don't see any elaboration here

Comment: Updated. I'm just trying to understand Lloyd's algorithm and k-means more.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about the running times of k means in practice.  You can construct distributions that make it take exponential time to run, but if those inputs are noised up a little bit, the running time will be polynomial.  http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/kMeans-socg.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A true k-means algorithm is in NP hard and always results in the optimum. Lloyd's algorithm is a Heuristic k-means algorithm that "likely" produces the optimum but is often preferable since it can be run in poly-time.